# map automatically surjective?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $f:\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ be a non-zero group homomorphism. Is $f$ automatically surjective?

I don't think so. For example, if $f(1,1):=10$, then $f(n,m)=nm10$ for $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}$ is not surjective if I'm not mistaken.

Is it correct?

Comment: $f(n,m)=10nm$ is not a homomorphism. $f(m,n)=10(m+n)$ is. You could have $f(m,n)=10m$ and still have $f(1,1)=10$. Or you could have $f(m,n)=m+9n$ and have the $f$ surjective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define more than one element of the homomorphism to specify it, but I think your intuition is right. Suppose we define $f(a,b)=2(a+b)$. We can check that this is a homomorphism, but its image consists of only the even integers.

Answer (score 1):

No. Just consider the homomorphism defined by $\;f(1,0)=a,\;f(0,1)=b$. The image of this homomorphism is the ideal generated by $\gcd(a,b)$.